# WebCam is never ON

Tags: java, opencv, video-capture

I am trying to open the external cam to capture images using opencv. i wrote the below code and i also checked some questions related to this issue but, when i run the code, the external web cam does not turn the green LED ON 
-the LED that indicates the web cam is ON- and word "Opened" is printed on the screen. the word "Opened", as you see below in the code indicates that the cam is ON.

please let me know why i am receiving the word "Opened" while the LED of the web cam is not ON.

**Code**:

```
public class MainClass {

static {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
}

private final static int WEBCAM_SELECT = -1;
private final static int WEBCAM_BUILTIN = 0;
private final static int WEBCAM_EXTERNAL = 2;

static JFrame mediaFrame = new JFrame("Media");

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Thread camThread = new Thread(new ThreadCam(), "CamThread");
    camThread.setDaemon(true);

    VideoCapture vidCap = new VideoCapture(WEBCAM_EXTERNAL);
    vidCap.open(WEBCAM_EXTERNAL);

    Thread.sleep(10000);// wait 10 sec to initilize the device;

    if (vidCap.isOpened()) {
        System.out.println("opened");//after 10 seconds this word will be printed
        camThread.start();
    }
}
```

**Update**

kindly please the Thread.sleep(10000); line and the comments beside it.

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
}

private final static int WEBCAM_SELECT = -1;
private final static int WEBCAM_BUILTIN = 0;
private final static int WEBCAM_EXTERNAL = 1;

static JFrame mediaFrame = new JFrame("Media");

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Thread camThread = new Thread(new ThreadCam(), "CamThread");
    camThread.setDaemon(true);

    VideoCapture vidCap = new VideoCapture();
    vidCap.open(WEBCAM_EXTERNAL);

    Thread.sleep(10000);// wait 10 sec to initilize the device; upto this line the Cam is ON, but after the 10 secs, it is OFF again and the word "Opened" is printed

    if (vidCap.isOpened()) {
        System.out.println("opened");//after 10 seconds this word will be printed
        camThread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try to grab a frame to see result. If it said it is opened, it should be.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue before, and what i realized is, the following two lines:

```
VideoCapture vidCap =   new VideoCapture();
vidCap.open(WEBCAM_EXTERNAL);
```

are to instantiate an object of VideoCapture Class and to open a specific device.

and since .isOpened returned true, this means, the device you chose is successfully opened. Being the LED of ypur device is ON before the .isOpened() and OFF after .isOpened() was called, that does not mean the device you chose to open is not ON or failed to be opened, but, actually, it is open but you are not performing any operation derived from the device you chose to open.

For an example, after .isOpened try to call vidCap.grap() or do video streaming,, then th eLED should be ON again.

Answer (score 0):

Try using WEBCAM_EXTERNAL = 1; instead of WEBCAM_EXTERNAL = 2;

I'm wondering what is your hardware, a PC/MAC?

Comment: kindly please have a look at the update section above..the problem still persistent. i am using Win8, sonyVaio